# Which one performance better when I use jedis , set(byte[], byte[]) or set(String, String)?

Tags: java, string, performance, serialization, redis

On my laptop, set `String` directly is always proformace better than set `byte[]`, even with `Serialization mechanism` when I test with `Jedis`. I am confused that if `String` should be serialized when call jedis `set(String, String)`? If `Serialization mechanism` happend, isn't is the default mechaism as I write in my `SerializeUtil` below? 
My code is below:

```
   public void testRedis() {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.append(i);
            jedis.set(sb.toString(), value);
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("default: " + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.append(i);
            jedis.set(sb.toString().getBytes(), value.getBytes());
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("byte: " + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.append(i);
            jedis.set(SerializeUtil.serDefaultString(sb.toString()), SerializeUtil.serDefaultString(value));
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("default ser: " + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.append(i);
            jedis.set(SerializeUtil.serUTFString(sb.toString()), SerializeUtil.serUTFString(value));
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("utf ser: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
```

Maybe `SerializeUtil` is need :

```
public static byte[] serDefaultString(String data) {

        byte[] result = null;

        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray);
            try {
                oos.writeObject(data);
                oos.flush();
                result = byteArray.toByteArray();
            } finally {
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

public static byte[] serUTFString(String data) {

        byte[] result = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray);
            try {
                oos.writeUTF(data);
                oos.flush();
                result = byteArray.toByteArray();
            } finally {
                oos.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is anyone can tell me why?

Replace `String` operation `+` to `StringBuilder`, now `set(String, String)` is still faster than other approach.

Another question, Is it necessary to `serialize` String to bytes when work with `set(byte[], byte[])` or just call `String.getBytes[]` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Thanks, I am studying it and it's helpful!

Comment: You could use Kryo for byte[] formatting routine... I tested it on my laptop with 1000 thread in parallel and could 3 time faster than string read/write in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

set( byte[], byte[] ) is more efficient because, when you use String, they are converted in byte[] internally in Jedis before being encoded in the communication buffer.

Now, the problem is you do not have any cheap byte[] formatting routines in the standard library like you have with String. Using serialization classes to just format a buffer is too expensive. What you would need is a StringBuilder for byte[] (i.e. a ByteBuilder class with formatting options).

Something like this:
https://code.google.com/p/coding4play/source/browse/trunk/Server/src/gameserver/util/ByteBuilder.java?r=63

Comment: I do serialization in my SerializeUtil, doesn't it make things better since I transfer String to byte[] by myself?

Comment: Yes, but this gain is offset by the fact ByteArrayOutputStream is much less efficient than the implicit StringBuilder which is used when you apply + to format your strings.